# mysql: how to select email_id for which has multiple actions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like following, email_id is unique to each email while each mail may have multiple actions like both open and unsub, how do I query email_ids with multiple actions? like search email_ids with both unsub and open as actions?

```
email_id   action 
1            open
1            click
2            click
3            open
3            unsub
```

Comment: Go on. Try something

Answer (score 0):

This is simple with `group by` and `having`:

```
select emailid
from t
having min(action) <> max(action);
```

If you want to limit this to particular actions, then use a `where` clause, such as `where action in ('unsub', 'open')`.